# Add a count column without grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to add a column to my dataframe which counts the number of observations in another column

Here is an example:

```
   df <- data.frame(colour=c("blue","blue","blue","green","green","orange","grey"))
```

And this is the output I am hoping for:

```
  colour count 
1   blue   3
2   blue   3
3   blue   3
4  green   2
5  green   2
6  orange  1 
7  grey    1
```

I could do this with a join:

```
count <- df %>% group_by(colour) %>% tally()
df <- df %>% left_join(count)
```

But I would rather do it in one statement

Comment: `df %>% group_by(colour) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: @AntoniosK or just `df %>% add_count(colour)`.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes! I always forget about this...